# WPF controls visibility throught IMultiValueConverter

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have control with [RadioButtons](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745072(v=vs.85).aspx). 
Each `RadioButton` represent some state of document. Each document have a lot of labels, buttons and another trash.
I need to collapse different labels, buttons, other...
In different states.
I think that I am building big crutch. What is the better way to implement this functionality?

**XAML**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1.Converters"
        xmlns:enums="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1.Enums"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:MultiBooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="Converter" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <RadioButton Content="First" x:Name="First"></RadioButton>
            <RadioButton Content="Second" x:Name="Second"></RadioButton>
            <RadioButton Content="Third" x:Name="Third"/>
            <RadioButton Content="Fourth" x:Name="Fourth"></RadioButton>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="1">
            <Label Content="Test1">
                <Label.Visibility>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource Converter}">
                        <MultiBinding.ConverterParameter>
                            <x:Array Type="{x:Type sys:Enum}">
                                <enums:DocumentTypes>Second</enums:DocumentTypes>
                                <enums:DocumentTypes>Fourth</enums:DocumentTypes>
                            </x:Array>
                        </MultiBinding.ConverterParameter>
                        <Binding ElementName="First" Path="IsChecked" />
                        <Binding ElementName="Second" Path="IsChecked" />
                        <Binding ElementName="Third" Path="IsChecked" />
                        <Binding ElementName="Fourth" Path="IsChecked" />
                    </MultiBinding>
                </Label.Visibility>
            </Label>
            <Label Content="Test2">
                <Label.Visibility>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource Converter}">
                        <MultiBinding.ConverterParameter>
                            <x:Array Type="{x:Type sys:Enum}">
                                <enums:DocumentTypes>First</enums:DocumentTypes>
                                <enums:DocumentTypes>Third</enums:DocumentTypes>
                            </x:Array>
                        </MultiBinding.ConverterParameter>
                        <Binding ElementName="First" Path="IsChecked" />
                        <Binding ElementName="Second" Path="IsChecked" />
                        <Binding ElementName="Third" Path="IsChecked" />
                        <Binding ElementName="Fourth" Path="IsChecked" />
                    </MultiBinding>
                </Label.Visibility>
            </Label>
            <Label Content="Test3">
                <Label.Visibility>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource Converter}">
                        <MultiBinding.ConverterParameter>
                            <x:Array Type="{x:Type sys:Enum}">
                                <enums:DocumentTypes>Fourth</enums:DocumentTypes>
                                <enums:DocumentTypes>First</enums:DocumentTypes>
                            </x:Array>
                        </MultiBinding.ConverterParameter>
                        <Binding ElementName="First" Path="IsChecked" />
                        <Binding ElementName="Second" Path="IsChecked" />
                        <Binding ElementName="Third" Path="IsChecked" />
                        <Binding ElementName="Fourth" Path="IsChecked" />
                    </MultiBinding>
                </Label.Visibility>
            </Label>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**ENUM**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WpfApplication1.Enums
{
    public enum DocumentTypes
    {
        First, Second, Third, Fourth
    }
}
```

**CONVERTER**

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Data;
using WpfApplication1.Enums;

namespace WpfApplication1.Converters
{
    class MultiBooleanToVisibilityConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            Dictionary<string, bool> dict = new Dictionary<string, bool>();
            dict.Add("First", (bool)values[0]);
            dict.Add("Second", (bool)values[1]);
            dict.Add("Third", (bool)values[2]);
            dict.Add("Fourth", (bool)values[3]);
            if (parameter != null)
            {
                List<DocumentTypes> result = ((IEnumerable)parameter).Cast<DocumentTypes>().ToList();
                foreach (DocumentTypes type in result)
                {
                    if (dict[type.ToString()])
                    {
                        return System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
                    }
                }
            }
            return System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you should use styles with triggers - unfortunatelly I cannot show you how, I'm not that good in WPF.

Comment: For one don't like the tight couple to enum value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**OPTION A**

As proposed by @t3chb0t, you could realize it as XAML-only solution with triggers:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <RadioButton Content="First" x:Name="First"></RadioButton>
        <RadioButton Content="Second" x:Name="Second"></RadioButton>
        <RadioButton Content="Third" x:Name="Third"/>
        <RadioButton Content="Fourth" x:Name="Fourth"></RadioButton>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="1">
        <Label Content="Test1">
            <Label.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Label">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=First}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=Fourth}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Label.Style>
        </Label>
        <Label Content="Test2">
            <Label.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Label">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=First}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=Third}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Label.Style>
        </Label>
        <Label Content="Test3">
            <Label.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Label">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=Fourth}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=First}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Label.Style>
        </Label>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

The downside is, that the logic is blurred in XAML and therefore difficult to read and extended.

**OPTION B**

A second option is to use a view model (let it call `MainViewModel`) and data binding:

- Create an enum with one value for each of the radio buttons
- Bind the selected value of the radio buttons to a property of the view model
- Create on view model for the labels (let it call `LabelViewModel`).
- Give the `MainViewModel` a list of `LabelViewModel`s and bind them to an `ItemsControl` with a `Label` as `DataTemplate`
- Update the `LabelViewModel`s within the `MainViewModel` if the selected value of the radio buttons changed.

That approach is better to understand and extend IMHO.

Comment: This is exactly what I meant ;-D as to _The downside is, that the logic is blurred in XAML_ I think you can move the _logic_ (the triggers) into a resource dictionary and make it appliable to any control with that style not just in this xaml file.